Get-ChildItem -File | Measure-Object -Property -Sum -Average -Minimum -Maximum
So learning ps for the 100th time and its suff like this that keeps tripping me up.
a basic task.. I want all files in a folder, get the sum of files, average of files, minimum and maximum of files.  In my head I would 1. get-help get-childitem, 2, get-help measure-object.  I would come to the following...
get-childitem -file | measure-object -property -sum -average -minimum -maximum
The above will not work.  I scratch my head for hours because im missing "length"
it should be:
Get-ChildItem -File | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum -Average -Minimum -Maximum
my question is how as a beginner am I supposed to know to plug in length?  Its these gotyas that put me off learning
BTW i am going throught https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.4
Tried - Get-ChildItem -File | Measure-Object -Property -Sum -Average -Minimum -Maximum
Expecting below - I don't even know where count came from.
Count    : 17
Average  : 80826320.0588235
Sum      : 1374047441
Maximum  : 880614528
Minimum  : 0
Property : Length

Which property?


I don't even know where count [the Count property in the output] came from

What Measure-Object can always do is to count the input objects it receives via the pipeline.
It does so invariably and by default, so that the Count property of the Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo instance that reports the measuring results is always filled in.[1]
Note: To determine what .NET type(s) a given cmdlet outputs, you have several options:

Consult the Outputs section of the online help topic (this example links to the relevant section of the Measure-Object)

If you have local help installed (which is true by default for Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1, but not for PowerShell (Core) 7 (the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition), where you must call Update-Help first), e.g.:
(Get-Help Measure-Object).returnValues


Note that a quick way to open the online help topic for a given cmdlet (if available) is to use Get-Help's -Online switch, e.g. Get-Help -Online Measure-Object.

Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to do the same for conceptual help topics (e.g. about_Output_Streams, operators, or .NET types. The following third-party functions (authored by me), stored in MIT-licensed GitHub Gists, fill this gap. Assuming you have looked at their source code (which I can personally assure you is safe, but you should always check), you can install them directly as follows:
# Show-Help function (wrapper for Get-Help -Online with support for about_* topics); e.g.
#     Show-Help about_pwsh
#     Show-Help about_Automatic_Variables PSItem
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/880624fd665073bb439dfff5d71da886/raw/Show-Help.ps1 | iex

# Show-OperatorHelp function (online help for PowerShell's operators; e.g.
#    Show-OperatorHelp replace
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/146f3202a810a74cb54a2d353ee4003f/raw/Show-OperatorHelp.ps1 | iex

# Show-TypeHelp function (online documentation for .NET types and instances); e.g.
#    Show-TypeHelp System.IO.FileSystemInfo
#    Show-TypeHelp datetime tostring
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/50a1b101cd53978cd147b4b138fe6ef4/raw/Show-TypeHelp.ps1 | iex


The relevant GitHub feature requests that suggests that this functionality be built into PowerShell in the future are:

Online support for about_... help topics #13550
Extend Get-Help to support focused lookup of documentation for PowerShell operators #11339
Extend Get-Help to support online documentation lookup for built-in .NET types #11338






The above solutions list all types that a cmdlet can output, which can vary depending on the specifics of a given call, namely the specific arguments passed or the implied provider context.

If you want to know what types a specific call outputs, use the Get-Member cmdlet; e.g.:
Get-ChildItem -File | Get-Member | Select-Object TypeName -Unique


To learn about the members of the distinct types among the output objects (properties, methods, events), simply omit the | Select-Object TypeName -Unique part.





In order to use switches such as -Sum, -Minimum, -Maximum, -Average, the input must self-evidently be numeric.
The System.IO.FileInfo instances that Get-ChildItem -File outputs are obviously not numeric as a whole, but have numeric properties.
Therefore, it stands to reason that you must tell Measure-Object which numeric property to operate on, which you can do by passing its name to the -Property parameter.
As you can tell from Measure-Object's syntax diagrams (most easily invoked with Measure-Object -?), the -Property parameter requires an argument:
 Measure-Object ... [[-Property] <System.String[]>] ...

That is, the parameter requires an argument of type System.String[] (in Windows PowerShell), i.e. one or more (an array of) strings containing property names (if you provide more than one, you'll get a Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo output object for each).

The [...] enclosure denotes optional elements, which in this case means:

The outer [...] indicates that a -Property argument can be omitted altogether - in which case Measure-Object operates on the input objects as a whole.

The inner [...], around -Property, indicates that an argument may be passed positionally, i.e. without explicitly preceding it with the target parameter name (-Property).




Note that the only parameters that do not require an argument in PowerShell are switch (flag) parameters (of type [switch]), such as Measure-Object's -Sum switch.

Your question implies that your intent is to operate on the (byte) size of the input objects representing files.
Somewhat unfortunately, the name of the relevant property on System.IO.FileInfo instances is Length - there is no way around discovering this by either reading the online help topic or inferring the property name from Get-Member output.
Therefore, to restate the working command from your question, you need (case doesn't matter, but I'm using case-exact names for readability):
Get-ChildItem -File |
  Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -Average -Minimum -Maximum


[1] However, note that using any combination of the -Line, -Word or -Character switches results in a different output type, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TextMeasureInfo, focused on measuring text (string) input.

I'm assuming when you refer to getting the sum,average,min,max of files you are referring to the content that is inside of the files.
If that is the case and you want to get the sum,average,min and max it is pretty straight forward.
Get-ChildItem -File | Foreach-Object {

  # gets the content in the file
  $file_content = get-content $_.Name;

  # writes the filename and contents to the screen
  Write-host "$($_.Name) = $($file_content)";

  # pass thru for measure-object
  $file_content;

} | Measure-object -Sum -Average -Maximum -Minimum

Screenshot below shows an example with 3 files.

file1.txt contains 2
file2.txt contains 5
file3.txt contains 8


